# As a contractor, what information do you need from the company to complete tax?

Tags: contractors, canada, taxes

I'm not very skilled at doing tax. I had worked as a contractor for a few different companies, and most have told me "as a contractor I'm responsible for doing my own tax". This isn't very clear to me because aren't I always responsible for doing my own tax? I guess what is meant is they didn't take off any earnings.

Does the company have to give you any information, such as a T4, T4A or other? According to [this non-government site](https://www.youngassociates.ca/news/2014/11/13/t4as-should-we-or-shouldnt-we) they should, but I asked the companies and they said they wouldn't. If they don't, then do I file tax as self employed? Does being a contractor mean your self-employed?

Comment: The only info you need is how much you invoiced them. Get an accountant, fast.

Comment: This seems like it'd be more at home on [freelancing.se]. Note that your last sentence is really a separate question (which may or may not be answerable depending on how this works in Canada).

Comment: @Lilienthal the last part is definitely answerable. I think while there are 2 questions here, they are both on topic. Maybe a bit of an edit is required. Self employment questions seems to me as still on topic and this one is pretty straightforward

Comment: Are you actually a self employed contactor or do you work through a 3rd party aka a body shop,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always responsible to file your own taxes, but it gets a bit more complicated than that.

As a salaried employee, my employer provides me with a T4 slip. On this T4 slip is all of the information I need to file my taxes such as total income, total taxes paid, CPP and EI contributions, unions dues etc.

As a contractor, you are your own employer (or you own the company that is your employer) and as such it is your duty to deduct the proper amounts from you check and "provide" yourself with a T4. T4 slips only apply to salaried employee. Most contractors are not paid in this fashion and because of this, they are not required to give you a T4 slip as they have not been deducting anything (that was your job as the employer). They should be able to tell much you were paid total, but that's about it.

So what these companies mean, is that because you are your own employer and they contacted you, you need to come up with tax data by yourself. This may seem confusing, but think of it this way:

If you hire a contractor to come build a house for you, do you give him any tax information that he can use come tax time? No. The same applies to software or any other field. Because you are the "company" they hire, you are one that must prepare the tax documents.

Taxes are not the only thing you should be concerned about here. You also need to be paying into the Canada Pension Plan (CPP) and Employment Insurance (EI). If I were you, I would contact an accountant ASAP to try and figure this out before the end of April (End of tax filing for Canada). Deductions in Canada can be tricky when you are  a contractor. For this year, I would highly recommend getting an accountant until you understand what needs to be done.

Comment: In addition to getting an accountant, you also need to make a collection of all paperwork relevant to your business, especially all receipts for anything that is remotely connected to your business. If you drove to a job by car, they will need the distance travelled total, how much of that was for work purposes, and receipts for any fluids you filled into your car. If you bought a computer that you use to write invoices, they will need the invoice for that. In the first year, just give them everything, they will tell you what they can't use.

Comment: @SimonRichter a very good point. I was going to add something to that affect, but I figured the accountant would guide OP in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are working as a contractor. You are either self employed or you have a limited liability company. You or your limited liability company give these companies bills, the bills get paid, and that's it. The money you get is your income if you are self employed, or your revenue if you have the company. The rest is up to you.

The question that you are asking is *way* beyond something that could be answered here. I would very, very strongly recommend that you **get an accountant as soon as humanly possible**. That accountant will tell you what to do, and you do exactly what they tell you, both to keep you on the right side of the tax laws, and to make sure you pay as little taxes as possible.

Comment: Some times people use the term contractor but they are actually employed by a third party.

Comment: @Neuromancer This person obviously isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past *cough* decades I have contracted in 15 countries on 3 continents, and I have ***always*** pad an accountant.

Actually, a tax preparer, rather than accountant. I just keep records – invoices, payslips & receipts for everything – and hand them to my tax preparer at the end of the year.

Even in the USA, where I might have gotten away with form 1040EZ, I paid H& Block (hint, for anything other than straightforward, which you are, pay extra for the “executive “ service). Accountants do two things.

An accountant will  help you avoid potential legal problems,  plus the save you multiple times what you pay for their services (at least, mine always have).

And Buddha help you  if you ever work in the UK. Almost every other country has a Jan 1 to Dec 31 tax year, whereas in the UK it is from April to Match (5th or 15th or April, IRRC, just to make it worse :-) Given that 181 days residence generally makes you liable for tax, imagine a year split between Germany and UK :-/

Drop whatever you are doing, and get a local accountant now. If you evasion a tax year split between two countries, it might help to find one  with international experience. That would also help them understand the different allowances. E.g a German tax preparer who has only ever worked for locals won’t know that a newcomer to his country is allowed a 50 Eur per diem for the first 90 days, in addition to other allowances. That Eur 4,500 ir Eur 2,240 after tax, so no  to be sniffed at. I paid Eur 200 a few years back to the guy who prepared my taxes and told me that.  Money well spent.

In general, you can claim any expenses that you would not have at home. E.g. not food, beyond that per diem, as you would be eating at home anyway. All rent & utility expenses, if you can prove a main residence in your home country, and lots more that you won’t know but your accountant.

Sorry if this veered a little off topic, from what records you need to keep, to how a tax preparer can save you money, but the answer in both cases is a text preparer. Hew will tell you want records you need to keep, ***and*** save you money; lots of it.

---

p.s keep up social security payments at home, to secure your government retirement pension. But contact them first, as you may be going to a country with a treaty, so you won’t have to pay at home, but will have to notify your home authorities to have overseas payments credited at home